# looping through user data in an object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I'm trying to loop through multiple user's data. Shown below:

```
const users = [
  {
    name: 'Homer', 
    role: 'Clerk', 
    dob: '12/02/1988',
    admin: false 
  }, 
  {
    name: 'Lisa', 
    role: 'Staff', 
    dob: '01/30/1965',
    admin: false 
  }, 
  {
    name: 'Marge', 
    role: 'Associate', 
    dob: '09/10/1980',
    admin: true 
  }
];
```

My code is below:

```
let namesAndRoles = (users) => {
  for (let [key,value] of Object.entries(users)) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
  }
};
//namesAndRoles(users)
```

Given an array of users, write a function, namesAndRoles that returns all of the user's names and roles in a string with each value labeled:

how do I get back users data in this form:

```
Name: Homer
Role: Clerk
```

Comment: `users` is an array, so why `Object.entries()` (and why `for (let [key,value] of ...)`)?

Comment: Loop (of some sort) + [Working with objects - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: I am trying to loop through and grab just two of the data entries but my code is not working. I believe I need to do nested loops to pull my data?

Answer (score 1):

`value` is an object which you are trying to log, you should access the specific property value like `value.name`.

You can try using [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> The `map()` method **creates a new array** populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
const users = [
  {
    name: 'Homer', 
    role: 'Clerk', 
    dob: '12/02/1988',
    admin: false 
  }, 
  {
    name: 'Lisa', 
    role: 'Staff', 
    dob: '01/30/1965',
    admin: false 
  }, 
  {
    name: 'Marge', 
    role: 'Associate', 
    dob: '09/10/1980',
    admin: true 
  }
];
let namesAndRoles = (users) => users.map(p => ({Name: p.name, Role: p.role}));
console.log(namesAndRoles(users));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [reducing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) the `users` Array to a string

```js
const users = [
  {
    name: 'Homer', 
    role: 'Clerk', 
    dob: '12/02/1988',
    admin: false 
  }, 
  {
    name: 'Lisa', 
    role: 'Staff', 
    dob: '01/30/1965',
    admin: false 
  }, 
  {
    name: 'Marge', 
    role: 'Associate', 
    dob: '09/10/1980',
    admin: true 
  }
];

console.log(users
  .reduce( (acc, val) =>
    `${acc}\nname: ${val.name}\nrole: ${val.role}\n`, ``)
  .trim()  // removes first \n)
);
```